# Create a t4 template for the unit test structure based on the model described by Phil Haack

Tags: t4

In [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/02/structuring-unit-tests.aspx) Phil Haack describes a model for structuring unit tests. Before I attempt to recreate it myself, I was wondering if anyone knew of t4 templates that exist to create the skeleton for this structure? I've been using it pretty frequently, but it does get repetitive.

For example, given the following class:

```
namespace My.Codes {
    public class Classy {

        public Classy(int x) {
             this.X = x;
        }

        public int X { get; private set; }

        public void DoSomething() {

        }
    }
}
```

I'd like a template that generates the following in the test project:

```
namespace My.Codes.Tests {
    public class ClassyTests {

        [TestClass]
        public class Ctor {

        }

        [TestClass]
        public class DoSomething {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not make the class partial or use the `metadatafor` attribute(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the T4 template wipe out your existing work when it runs again? Or are you just doing it in a run-once fashion to get the structure and then not rerunning it again afterward?

Comment: yeah, if you ran it again, it'd wipe everything

Comment: You could create a custom T4 template that appended to the file rather than blew it away.